# El proveedor 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' no está registrado en el equipo local para subir archivos en Excel (2024)

Tags: sql-server, excel

> Buenas tardes dias o noches, estoy tratando de instalar el proveedor Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 para subir archivos en excel en sql server pero no me aparece nada, use este link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920 para descargarlo
> e instale este archivo accessdatabaseengine_X64, nose que error puedo estar cometiendo